# Configure Danish keyboard on MacBook Pro running Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, macbook-pro

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a MacBook Pro with a Danish keyboard. Is there a way to remap the keys to the standard configuration? I am now using the *Danish (Machintosh, no dead keys)* layout and it's a bit painful to code.

Comment: Are you asking how to switch from the _Danish (Machintosh, no dead keys)_ layout to the basic _Danish_ layout? https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html

Comment: Problem solved! I got confused and thought that just because I have a Mac I had to use the Machintosh config. Thanks for the hint!